# Need help with proof with absolute value and complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers, absolute-value

Had some trouble trying to prove the following problem.

Prove that if $|z| < 1$ and $|w| < 1$, then

$$
\frac{|z-w|}{|1-\overline{z}w|} < 1
$$

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: In other words, $|z-w|\lt |1-\bar zw|$...

Comment: Hint: Multiply the LHS by $ 1 / |z|$ and show that the result is less than 1, so the the LHS is less than $|z|$, which is itself less than 1. Then go back and clean up the argument to handle the case when $z = 0$.

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2):

It is equivalent to $\lvert z-w\rvert^2 <\lvert 1-\bar zw\rvert^2$, i.e.:

\begin{align*}
&(z-w)(\bar z-\bar w) < (1-\bar zw)(1- z\bar w)\iff z\bar z+w\bar w <1+z\bar zw\bar w\\ \iff &1 -z\bar z-w\bar w+z\bar zw\bar w=(1-z\bar z)(1-w\bar w)=(1-\lvert z\rvert^2)(1-\lvert w\rvert^2)>0.
\end{align*}